# Classes composed by each others

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, composition

Consider this example of code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}      
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1() : Base() {}
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2() : Base() {}

};
```

Is there any to make that Derived1 *has-a* Derived2 and Derived2 *has-a* Derived1?
The best solution would be by using a third class which has those two objects. But in case high performance is needed?

An example might be a two-way client-server application.

EDIT: Consider that that's just a summary example. In the real code each of the three classes could throw an exception; I made sure that the code is exception-safe, though.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why would a forth object diminish performance?

Comment: @BrianBi, I think he wants the two classes to either be inherited from each other, or contain an object of the other?

Comment: Added in the first post: is it enough?

Comment: This question has rhyme or reason.

Comment: @EdHeal Aren't you missing a negation in there?

Comment: Ed - so you like it, right? :D

Comment: @Borgleader - sarcasm is the lowest form of whit

Comment: @EdHeal [rhyme or reason](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhyme%20or%20reason): good sense or reason. How is "this question has rhyme or reason" a valid close reason? That seems to describe a valid question.

Comment: Please do not go off topic anymore. Check the edit I've made, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish a "[has-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)" relationship with a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) which basically tells "this class exists, it's just not declared yet"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}      
};

// Forward declaration
class Derived1;

class Derived2 : public Base
{
    friend class Derived1;

public:
    Derived2() : Base() {}
private:    
    Derived1 *ptr;

};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1(Derived2& obj) : Base(), ptr(&obj) {
        obj.ptr = this;
    }
private:
    Derived2 *ptr;
};

int main() {

    Derived2 obj2;
    Derived1 obj1(obj2);



    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/RVU8AR

This way the two classes can communicate with each other. Notice the private pointers and the initialization into the constructor. With the "friend" declaration one class is able to modify the other class's private members.

Comment: I don't know whether to use pointers or a third class. Because I'd have to make 2 `Derived1` and 2 `Derived2` (one for the client application and one another for the server). 
Can't `ptr`s be initialized in the constructor in order to make them `private`?

Comment: sure, you can do that. Although one element needs to exist before its pointer can be taken. Some tricks can solve this as well or you can unleash templates power and do everything at compile time. Also keep in mind that a pointer is a light-weight element instead of another class.

Comment: Also: take a look at the new code. I used friend classes as well

Comment: It's a good point. I'm thinking it over, because using a third class would be more secure (because I'd make the objects on my own, rather then relying on user's input); performance _could_ get worse, though.
I'll be keeping thinking over, I should be able to get an answer soon.

Comment: not a big deal to be honest, if you just keep pointers around there will be a negligible performance overhead even with a third class. When you have big objects using pointers or move semantics (C++11) becomes almost mandatory.

Comment: Both solutions are good and both have some (little) downsides. Which one would you choose?

Comment: It depends on what I had to do. If you prefer a clearer design, go for the third class and handle permissions for the pointers. There might be other issues I can't see right now, depends on the context too.

Answer (score 0):

Each class can hold a pointer:?

```
class Derived1
    Derived2 *p_d2;
class Derived2
    Derived1 *p_d1;
```